# Create an animated credits text for my about box

Tags: delphi, animation, text, delphi-2010

in my application i've created an about box and i am wondering if i can show an animated text as credit ! Text animating from bottom to top of the dialog. Which components can i use for that or should i download in order to achieve a nice credits animated text in my about box.

Comment: I used to have animated credits, but I stopped... It caused more trouble than it was worth.  I had hyperlinks in the credits to the applicable websites.  It was nearly impossible to click on the right link, when they were moving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a standard `TMemo`, `TListBox`, etc and then scroll it manually from a `TTimer`.  `TWinControl`-derived controls inherit a public `ScrollBy()` method.  Some controls, like `TListView`, even have their own optimized `Scroll()` method.

Answer (score 5):

Try the [`TJvScrollText`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aTJvScrollText) component which is part of the [JVCL](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/).

Comment: @Rafik: If smooth scrolling or other details are important, make them part of the question instead of adding them as comments to answers you receive.

Answer (score 2):

If you want flashy credits animation, look at [KSDEV](http://www.ksdev.com/index.html)'s [VGScene](http://www.ksdev.com/wiki/index.php?title=VGScene) `VGScene's Credits Demo` in the `samples` directory. Remember, it was written by [Eugene Kryukov](http://www.facebook.com/people/Eugene-Kryukov/100002018700123) the man behind [Firemonkey](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/firemonkey)!

**Edit**

[image]